# BLDC does not start on its own using trapezoidal commutation

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, commutation

I am trying to control a brushless motor using trapezoidal commutation. I read the signals from the Hall sensors and switch the FETs of each motor phase accordingly. I run the commutation task at 1KHz. To modulate the speed I use PWM at 20KHz.

It all works fine in both directions at different speeds.

However, the motor only starts moving after I give it a little tap with my hand. It cannot start on its own from zero speed. What am I doing wrong?

The commutation sequence seems to be correct because if I modify it then the motor does not run at all. Also, if I swap two phases or two Hall sensors the motor does not move anymore. So I guess the current wiring setup is the right one.

I don't know for sure what kind of winding the motor has, but checking phase-to-phase voltage on a scope shows very smooth sinusoidal curves, so I'm guessing that could be an issue? I will try to implement sinusoidal commutation as well, but shouldn't trapezoidal also be able to get the motor up to speed from its standstill state?

Comment: If you use a V(avg)/f ratio , you may not have enough current to overcome stiction. Verify your starting current at threshold of motion.

Comment: "I run the commutation task at 1KHz. To modulate the speed I use PWM at 20KHz", can you elaborate these two sentences?

Comment: Then add commutation at DC speed and why is no load speed ratio = V/f

Comment: @MarkoBuršič The commutation task is responsible for checking the status of the Hall sensors and modifying the status of each motor phase accordingly. I execute that task every 1ms (1KHz). The PWM is totally unrelated and is responsible for modulating the voltage on the only motor phase that is high during each commutation segment. I run the PWM at 20KHz.

Comment: That's right; they don't naturally start on their own. You need a startup routine to implement the commutation sequence open-loop (on a timer, quite slowly, as if it was a stepper motor) and switches to normal operation once Hall sensor pulses start appearing. And at a fairly low PWM duty cycle (controls the start current). If you don't see sensor pulses, increase PWM to increase starting current...

Comment: Sorry everyone, I found a mistake in my program that prevented the phase voltages to be updated when there was no change in the Hall sensors state. So at zero speed there was essentially no commutation running. My bad. It is working fine now. Thanks for all your inputs.

Comment: @olmo You should trigger an interrupt at each hall sensor signal change, not a time task, rather an interrupt task.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Thank you for the excellent observation! I have a time task set up for the phase voltage modulation because when using sinusoidal commutation that's the only way to go (I think). There are no interrupts to respond to when modulating the phase voltage in between two Hall sensor edges. But you are right that when doing simple trapezoidal commutation it is more optimal to just modulate the voltage at the Hall edges and not at any other time. Thank you.

Comment: @olmo Answer your own question - and mark as solution so others can skip to the answer.